# VerticalAlignment="Stretch" for label inside canvas doesn't work

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, .net-4.0, vertical-alignment

How to use `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` with a `Label` inside a `Canvas`? I'm trying to center the text "Cancel" in the button as in the code below. To use fixed height and width for the label isn't a desired option.

```
<Button Name="buttonCancel" Width="80" Height="40" IsCancel="True" Padding="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Canvas>
        <Label Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0" Padding="0" FontSize="10">Esc</Label>
        <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Cancel</Label>
    </Canvas>
</Button>
```

Comment: "To use fixed height and width for the label isn't a desired option." Then why are you using `Canvas`? It's *only* for fixed-size layouts.

Comment: It's mainly because I think canvas is the only content control that can overlay children controls.

Comment: What gave you that idea? Try: `<Grid><Button Background="Green"/><Button Background="Blue" Margin="20 10"/></Grid>`

Comment: I wasn't clear, sorry. What I want is to have two labels inside a button. One will be the command text - like OK, Cancel, etc. - and the other will be accelerator key - like F2, ESC, Enter.

Comment: And the principle there is the same. Replace your `Canvas` with this: `<Grid><Label Padding="0" FontSize="10">Esc</Label><Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Cancel</Label></Grid>` Notice how the two labels are laid out inside the same space, just like the two `Button`s in my previous example? Much simpler, especially in the long run, than trying to force a `Canvas` to do something it was *specifically not designed for.*

Comment: Yes, you are right. Works like a charm! I'll adopt the solution you provided me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a binding to the `Canvas`'s `ActualWidth`:

```
<Canvas>
    <Label Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=ActualWidth}">...</Label>
</Canvas>
```

But as mentioned above, if you are interested in dynamic stretching layouts, the `Canvas` is not the ideal choice of control.

Answer (score 1):

A `Canvas` does not perform any scaling layout of its contents; if you want to scale the contents, you could use Grid in this case, which will, by default, scale both `Label` elements to fill the `Content` space.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you need the canvas for other objects that are of a fixed nature, you could overlay the `Canvas` on a `Grid`, and then put the labels in the grid.  You can put the labels before the canvas to make them background z-index (overwritten by canvas objects) or after the canvas to make them higher z-index (will overwrite canvas objects).  For example:

```
<Button Name="buttonCancel" Width="80" Height="40" IsCancel="True" Padding="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
        <Label Padding="0" FontSize="10">Esc</Label>
        <Label VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Cancel</Label>
        <Canvas>
            <!-- Your Canvas content here -->
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeating my solution from the comments, since (a) you really don't want a `Canvas` and (b) it sounds like this solved your problems, so I'll make it an answer where it will be more visible to others.

`Canvas` is meant for fixed-pixel-size layouts, which is probably the least common case. You should replace your `Canvas` with a `Grid` as shown below, so that both `Label`s are laid out dynamically (and independently) within the available space:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Padding="0" FontSize="10">Esc</Label>
    <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Cancel</Label>
</Grid>
```